# How to display no value for particular legend in amchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

[image]I have constructed a chart, In which I am displaying the legend. Initially, we sum up the value and display in legend. but I need to display 'N/A' for the particular legend.If I mouseover the chart we should display the value. Below I have attached the code I have done.

```
'legend': {
          'markerType': 'circle',
          'periodValueText': 'total: [[value.sum]]',
          'labelText': '[[title]] :',
          'valueText': '[[value]]',
          'valueWidth': 80,
          'valueFunction': function(legendData, valueText) {
                        var id = (typeof legendData.id !== 'undefined') ? legendData.id : legendData.graph.id;

                        if (id === 'D1' || id === 'D2') {

                            return valueText === '0' ? 'N/A' : valueText ;
                        }

                        return valueText;
                    }
                },
```

I have used a valuefunction to display N/A if the value is 0.But initially I should display N/A for id D1 and D2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `values` property in your legendData property to base your logic off of when to display N/A on hover or when to display N/A when you mouse out of the chart. This will make detecting what value to display easier to manage.

Here's how to default "N/A" for D1 and D2 on mouse out and when no mouse cursor is present on initial load:

```
  legend: {
    // ...
    valueFunction: function(legendData, valueText) {
      //values is available on mouseover
      if (legendData.values) {
        var id = legendData.graph.id;

        if (id === "D1" || id === "D2") {
          return valueText === "0" ? "N/A" : valueText;
        }
      }
      //initial value when no mouse cursor is present or on mouseout
      else if (legendData.id === "D1" || legendData.id === "D2") { 
        return "N/A";
      }

      return valueText;
    }
  },
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/89e83cad6dc901d7f31b6e4f0eb9044f?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks, @xorspark, I have implemented the code and its working well.